# I can't understand "Would's" meaning?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these two sentences?
are they substitutable in the context?

> How would you get so tan?
>
> How you get so tan?

Here is the context: (Friends season 10.03)

Ross: (looking at Monica's legs) WOW!

Chandler: Hey! Stop staring at my wife's legs! No no! Stop staring at your sister's legs!

Ross: I'm sorry, it's just... how would you get so tan?

Chandler: She went on one of those spray-on tan places.

Ross: Eh, you got a spray-on tan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence "How would you get so tan?"

However, it wouldn't make sense in this context. Because we have the word *would*, this phrase would describe a hypothetical situation:

Andrew: I'd like to go to Alice's pool party on Friday, but I'll only go if I can get as darkly tanned as Peter.

Ben: How would you get so tan? [*i.e. in the hypothetical world where you'll be going to that pool party, how would it be possible to get so tan in such a short amount of time?*]

That doesn't fit this context.  In this context, Monica *is* "so tan"; there's no hypothetical situation. How then to explain this? Your transcript is incorrect.  I've just listened to the dialogue. Ross says:

"How'd you get so tan?"

This *could* be a contraction of "how would," but from the context, we know that it's actually a contraction of "how did" as in "how did you get so tan [in the short amount of time since I last saw you]?"